# Avoid inserting duplicate value to a list in Java

Tags: java, list, duplicates

So I want to insert random integers to a list. However, I want to make sure that there are no duplicates on the list. Here is what I have done so far:

```java
while (options.size() <=4) {
    int i = 0;
    int random = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(answer - 8 ,answer + 8);
    if (random != answer && random != options.get(i-1)) {
        options.add(random);
        i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Use a Set instead.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is with a distinct random stream:

```
ThreadLocalRandom.current()
        .ints(answer - 8, answer + 8)
        .distinct()
        .limit(5)
        .forEach(options::add);
```

For better performance on bigger datasets, you can shuffle instead:

```
List<Integer> range = IntStream.range(answer - 8, answer + 8)
        .boxed()
        .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
Collections.shuffle(range);
options.addAll(range.subList(0, 5));
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you want distinct values in your collection, use a LinkedHashSet and add values in it.

```
Set<Integer> options = new LinkedHashSet<>();
while (options.size() <= 4) {
    int i = 0;
    int random = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(answer-8, answer+8);
    if (random != answer) {
        options.add(random);
        i++;
    }
}
```

Once done, you can convert the set to a list (if required for further processing)

```
List<Integer> list = set.stream().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score -1):

It turns out all I needed was the contain function

```
while (options.size() <=4){
        int i = 0;
        int random = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(answer -8 ,answer +8 );
        if (random != answer && !options.contains(random)){
            options.add(random);
            i++;
        }

    }
```

Comment: `contains` on a `List` is `O(n)` - that makes this algorithm a hugely inefficient `O(n^2)`. Use a `LinkedHashSet` instead.

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't use [java.util.Set](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Set.html)?